# Where can PATH to Thunderbird be set in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: path, thunderbird

I'd like to migrate to `Thunderbird 11` from `Thunderbird 3`. I installed `Thunderbird 3` using apt-get (the newer versions are not available in binary form, unfortunately, at least not in main, universe or multiverse repositories, don't like PPA's when not really necessary). So I downloaded tar.bz2 of the newest version and uncompressed into /usr/lib, next to where the old version lives. Now, I'd like the system to find `thunderbird` inside `Thunderbird 11` folder rather than the old one. How to I achieve that? I know there must be some sort of a `PATH` to `/usr/lib/thunderbird-3.1.20` set on my system, but just cannot find where it is. Checked all common places already, like:

- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d/*`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc` (though it shouldn't be here as `PATH` is also visible by GNOME)
- probably some other places I don't recall now.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird's particular directory is not in your path, and it does not need to be there.

You have a symbolic link in `/usr/bin` of name `thunderbird` pointing to the real executable/script launching Thunderbird. On my machine it is the following:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/thunderbird
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 2012-03-29 09:08 /usr/bin/thunderbird -> ../lib/thunderbird-11.0.1/thunderbird.sh
```

I think you can change this with

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/thunderbird-11/thunderbird.sh /usr/bin/thunderbird
```

or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of that possibility. BTW, is there a way to check which executable is being called when a command is executed in terminal?

Comment: @mmm: with `bash`, that on most Linux distros is the default shell, you can use `type -P name`.

Comment: Thanks again, knowing this would have probably solved my problem in the first place :).

Comment: @mmm: there's also `which`, which exists as both a binary and often a shell built-in, so is more portable: `which gimp` tells me `/usr/bin/gimp`.

Comment: @mmm No, do not change anything in `/usr/bin`. Put the symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin` instead. Otherwise, the next time you upgrade the Thunderbird package of your distribution, the symbolic link will be overwritten.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Don't use `which`, it's unreliable (because it's not a bash built-in, so it doesn't know about bash aliases and functions and cached commands). Use `type` instead, it's reliable and portable.

Comment: @Gilles: at least the `-P` switch is definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

It recommend using a PPA. It's easier than managing a manual installation. Don't install a program from a simple archive when not really necessary.

If you prefer to install a binary separately (the only good reason would be if there's no PPA with the version you want), the easiest way to make it accessible is to create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`. This directory is for executables that are intended for anyone on the system to run and that do not come with the distribution. It is normally before `/usr/bin` in the `PATH`, so if you have both `/usr/bin/thunderbird` and `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird` and you type `thunderbird`, then the one in `/usr/local/bin` is executed.

Do not unpack the `.tar.bz2` in `/usr/lib`. Generally speaking, never manually modify a file in `/bin`, `/lib`, `/sbin` or `/usr`, except under `/usr/local`. These places are reserved for the package manager. The usual place to put programs installed by unpacking an archive is `/opt` or `/usr/local/opt`. You should therefore unpack the archive under `opt`. Then create a symbolic link to the executable:

```
ln -s /opt/thunderbird-3.1.20/thunderbird /usr/local/bin/thunderbird
```

If you want to invoke Thunderbird from a shell that you started before creating the symbolic link, you may need to tell the shell to clear its path cache with the command `hash -r`.